# Database Error - Unknown column parent_is_draft in where clause using Playa plugin

Tags: ee2, playa

I have a channel in my website called Careers.  I have a playa field setup for locations.  I'm trying to add the location to the job posting in the careers channel.

After I hit submit, I get this error:

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'parent_is_draft' in 'where clause'
DELETE FROM `exp_playa_relationships` WHERE `parent_entry_id` = '440' AND `parent_field_id` = '26' AND `parent_is_draft` = 0
Filename: third_party/playa/ft.playa.php
Line Number: 2558

Has anyone every seen this error before?  Do you have any idea how to fix it?

EE v2.7.3
Playa Plugin v4.4.5

Also use Blueprints and Structure plugins in our EE install.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added your license key in the fieldtype settings. This is required for the plugin to update your database tables correctly.

Comment: If i uninstall it will it remove all of the data associations or does that data remain intact?  We may be using Playa in multiple places and have several connections made with it throughout our website

Comment: Unfortunately it would, maybe you should contact pixel and tonic about this matter.

Comment: thanks, i will try that...i'm gonna do something before i contact them to see if i can fix it.  I'm checking the Playa fieldtype screen and at first i got an error.  Revisiting that page now i see my license key field is blank.  So, I'm going to fill that in and see what we get.

Comment: actually, see my edit

Comment: Thanks jonathon, I think we fixed it.  I added my license key and submitted that fieldtype Playa page.  I was able to update my careers post and add a location and submit that page without the site breaking.  Yes, your edit is right on the money except submitting the Playa fieldtype page i read adds that column for me.  So, the best solution is to submit the fieldtype page because then you don't need to mess with the DB.

Comment: if you update your answer to say that adding the license key and submitting the fieldtype screen will correct this error then I'll mark your answer as the right one.  I'd like to give you credit since you helped me.  Thanks again!